# Equilibrium conditions established in the following scenario

Tags: pressure, equilibrium, gas

If I was to create a setup as demonstrated below, where I have seperated a container into two halves of equal volumes, and in both halves, I half placed a different gas such that the final pressure they exert on the valves are equal, and the temperatures are also equal, but number of moles vary to satisfy their respective state equations.

[image]

My query is, if I was to remove the valve, would gas molecules exchange? And if so, till when? My teacher claims that it shall rearrange until the pressure of gas 1 on the left half and right half becomes equal and the same for gas 2, but I don't quite agree with him.

`My Thoughts Till Now:`
From a macroscopic viewpoint it seems, that the gases shouldn't exchange,but that was if we were to treat the surface of a gas as a continuous body. From a microscopic view, gases are small particles, and their pressure is not due to a continuous surface, rather it's due to collisions. And hence at the interface, clearly, gas molecules can, and should exchange. But this analysis doesn't give any reason as to why pressure of each gases in both the halves should be same.

Comment: If you remove the partition, gas 1 expands to fill the container because this increases entropy. Gas 2 also expands to fill the container because this increases entropy. Entropy is maximized when the pressure is uniform. Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: I suppose, that is what I was looking for. But mechanically, is equilibrium only established when the pressure is uniform, and if so is there any better reason to think of it mechanically rather than from entropy?
I was thinking of one reason which might make justify it but I am bit unclear on it.
The true equilbrium condition should be such that the number of gaseous molecules of gas 1 escaping from left to right on the interface, should be the same as the number of molecules moving from right to left. But in every type of interface, will only uniform pressure ensure that?

Comment: Ideal gas behavior is entirely entropic. At the atomic level, it's assumed that there are no interactions that might be modeled using mechanics. Every gas simply expands as much as it's able.

Comment: @Chemomechanics ok, thank you. I'd like to ask another thing here, if I was to puncture the valve and assume them to be ideal for the sake of simplicity, would they follow the same rate of effusion compared to a case when there was no gas present in the opposite half of the container?

Comment: Probably not.  .